# Can I call stop flag in a multithreaded env?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, undefined-behavior

Is calling the function `Foo:kill` thread safe, I think not as some threads will be reading the `m_kill`. If nothing will be corrupted (no undefined behaviour) I don't mind threads reading different values, they should catch up I beleive. Not sure, should I use `std::atomic_bool` or this is thread safe please as only only one user is writting and all thread are reading?

```
class Foo
{
public:

    void build()
    {
        const std::size_t dummy = 4;
        auto op = [this]() -> void
        {
            while(!this->m_kill) process();
        };

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < dummy; i++)
        {
            m_threads.emplace_back(std::thread(std::cref(op)));
        };
    };

    void kill()
    {
        m_kill = true;
    }

    void process()
    {

    };

private:
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
    bool m_kill;
};
```

Please don't worry about the `join` and all implemetation issues :)

Comment: Last I checked, there is no requirement that the compiler produce code that would necessarily read the value more than once in looping situations. You don't have one here, but I never put it past the compiler to inline some loop calling `build` and end up reading `this->m_kill` only once, caching it, and never checking again. I'd *strongly* recommend using an atomic `bool`; you can explicitly load and store to it with `std::memory_order_relaxed` to avoid most of the overhead of atomics, while still forcing the compiler to actually perform the check of memory, not use cached reads.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to minimize overhead, but as you mentioned `relaxed` sounds fine. Thanks very much!

Comment: On an unrelated note, that's not a very good placement to check `m_kill`. It will only be checked once at thread startup and never gain. I assume you have simplified the code to such a degree that any checks in the `process` function have been removed?

Comment: AAAAH sorry there is a loop somewhere, sorry :) I have changed!

Comment: The code shown exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race on the non-atomic object `m_kill`. You have to make it atomic in order to avoid this undefined behavior.